# Change object on KVO path

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I have an object A, which have a property B. B is an object that have a property C of type *int*. Then in another object, I use KVO to observe object A with keypath ***B.C***. If I change value of C, then I can receive notification fine. But if I assign another object to B, or allocate B to a new object, would I also receive notification?

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to what you mean by assigning or allocating another object to B. As far as I understand you have a variable named B that references the object you are observing. KVO works with objects, not variables so if you point your variable B to another object the KVO will remain in place and will not automatically extend to the other object. Hope this helps.